# make image fit full screen without scroll bars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make a header image full screen. I tried this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

But here is the picture:

[image]

Somehow window still need to scroll down as you can see, how can i fix this, to fit in screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
.img-responsive { background-size: 100%; }
```

OR

```
.img-responsive { background-size: cover; }
```

OR (based on revised question)

Add this to `body`:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `img` tag, use `background-image` for fullscreen image.

```
<header>
  <div class="menu_area">...</div>
</header>


html, body, header {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    background-image: url('images/image1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```