# Loading gif in WebView not adjusting to WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I'm trying to load a gif into `WebView`, it's working ok, but the problem is that I see this :

[image]

The problem is that I can scroll and I'm not seeing the .gif completly in the `WebView`.

My `html` is :

```
<html style="margin: 0;">
<body style="margin: 0;">
<img src="tuto1.gif" style="width: 40%; height: 70%" />
</body>
</html>
```

And my `WebView` in xml file is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewPager"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text="Page One" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm showing this `html` following :

```
WebView wv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewPager);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/tuto1.html");
wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

### NOTE: My .gif is 330 x 750

### What is my goal?

I want to see my .gif in that space on the screen and I do not want it to be scrollable I want to show the full "web".

I've tried also `Glide` but when I put that .gif into an `ImageView` it lags so hard that's why I use a `webView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should try using this https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable instead of wasting time play with infamous Android error-prone webview.

Comment: Could you post an example? getting a .gif from .raw? if it works I'll mark your answer as a correct.

Comment: Can't get it, what do you mean "getting a .gif from .raw"?
What is ".raw" here?
Have a looks at the lib above, it works with .gif files as other normal drawable picture files (.png, .jpg)

Comment: and please, edit your question, add some text to the picture for example to clarify where is the gif image, where is the pager, what do you really want to do...bla bla, otherwise others can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re problem can be solved with css 
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508585/make-image-fit-full-screen-without-scroll-bars)

Use this style for `Body` tag :

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I did this : <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;"> and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Metadata

Comment: What's that? What's settings?

Comment: I see difference but it's not adjusting... I can not see the full gif

Comment: So, what you see?

Comment: less zoom but not all the image

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
    <body style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
      <img src="tuto1.gif" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
   </body>
</html>


 <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

</WebView>




        webViewDetail.clearCache(true);
        webViewDetail.clearHistory();
        webViewDetail.clearFormData();


        WebSettings webSettings = webViewDetail.getSettings();
        // To enable java script on page.
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //To always load page from web server, not to use resources from cache.
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        String absoulteFileUrlPath = "file://" + singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
        webViewDetail.loadUrl(absoulteFileUrlPath);
```

Comment: If i follow your steps it works but it overlays the rest of views... I'd like to put the WebView like for example 250x200 and fit the image gif on it... is it possible instead of using matchparent?

Comment: allocate height and width to webview

Comment: If I do this I can scroll on webview

Comment: I don't want it to scroll! I just want the WebView FIT in 220dpx250dp and see the full image in those space

Comment: then you need to allocate height and width to webview